# How to turn list into string with quotation marks for each value?

Tags: r, list, transform

I have a list:

```
id<- c('22~1', '85L3~1')
```

I want to turn it into string like this:

```
id IN ('22~1', '85L3~1')
```

How could i do that? When i try this:

```
id<- c('22~1', '85L3~1')


id<- glue("id IN ('{paste(id, collapse=', ' )}')")
```

I get this:

```
id IN ('22~1, 85L3~1')
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help:

```
#Code
glue("id IN ('{paste(id, collapse='\\',\\'' )}')")
```

Output:

```
id IN ('22~1','85L3~1')
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can use `sprintf`

```
sprintf("id IN ('%s')", toString(id))
#[1] "id IN ('22~1, 85L3~1')"
```